# Get data from firestore and put into array in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app in angular, and one task is, I need read data from Firestore and save into an array, my code snippet is as below:

```js
public getListingData(): Observable < RequestListingModel > {
  console.log("getting listing...");
  
  this.firestore.collection('Requests').snapshotChanges().subscribe(
    requests => {
      this._listRequestItems = requests.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as RequestItemModel;
        data.requestId = a.payload.doc.id;

        console.log("doc found - " + data.requestId);
        return data;
      })

    });

  const requestListingModel = {
    items: this._listRequestItems
  }
  as RequestListingModel;

  return of(requestListingModel);
}
```

And my code of RequestListingModel is as below:

```
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';

export class RequestItemModel {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  category: string;
  requestId: string;
  postBy: string;
  description: string;
  // Default mock value
  // expirationDate = '12/01/2018';
  expirationDate: string = dayjs().add(5, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss') as string;
}

export class RequestListingModel {
  items: Array<RequestItemModel> = [];

  constructor(readonly isShell: boolean) { }
}
```

And it's not working as I always get empty return when call the function getListingData(), but the console can print out the each requestId successfully, I think something wrong with the way I store into array, please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is happening because things are happing asynchronously:

So `return of(requestListingModel);` gets called before `this.firestore.collection('Requests').snapshotChanges().subscribe(...)` populates the array, thus returning an observable of an empty array.

Since it looks like you want to return an observable, don't `subscribe()` inside your method.  Just do a `map()` on the `snapshotChanges` observable to transform the output, and let the consuming code subscribe to your `getListingData()` method.

```
public getListingData(): Observable < RequestListingModel > {
    console.log("getting listing when someone subscribes...");


    return this.firestore.collection('Requests').snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(requests => { 
            let requestListingModel = {
                items: []
            } as RequestListingModel;

            requests.map(a => {
                let data = a.payload.doc.data() as RequestItemModel;
                data.requestId = a.payload.doc.id;

                console.log("doc found - " + data.requestId);

                requestListingModel.items.push(data);
            });

            return requestListingModel;
        })
    );
}
```

Note: still... can't test this at the moment, so it may not be 100% correct :-\
But hopefully points you in the right direction. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change to use map and it got error: "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentChangeAction<{}>[]>'", so I use "pipe" and the error is gone, but now I got new error: "Type 'RequestItemModel[]' is not assignable to type 'RequestListingModel[]'".

Comment: Now my code is like this ```public getListingData(): Observable<RequestListingModel> {
    console.log("getting listing...");

    return this.firestore.collection('Requests').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(
      requests => requests.map(a=> {
          let data = a.payload.doc.data() as RequestItemModel;
          data.requestId = a.payload.doc.id;

          console.log("doc found - " + data.requestId);
          return data;
        }
      )
      ) 
    );  } ```

Comment: oh yeah! I forgot `pipe()`.  As for the type mis-match, yeah the way it is now, it's emitting the individual `RequesItemModel`, not sending them in a group.  I'm modifiy my answer real quick to output a single `RequestListingModel`...

Comment: @Derrick.X, I updated it.  Again, there's no money-back guarantee on this as it isn't tested, but should get you close :-)

Comment: yeah, it works, you saved my day, thank you so much :-)